# Convert for loop/print output to string? Python

Tags: python, string

```
def reveal():
    guessright = 0
    for letter in secretword:
        if letter == usertry:
            guessright = guessright + 1
            print usertry,
        else:
            print "_",
    return guessright

reveal()
```

When using reveal() something like _ _ _ _ a _ will be printed by the for loop- is there a way of converting what it prints into a string, or getting the function to return 2 outputs, the integer guessright, and the stuff that was printed while reveal() was running?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, there are lots of ways -- The simplest is to use a list to hold the data (appending new data rather than printing) and then `''.join` it at the end:

```
def reveal():
    text = []
    guessright = 0
    for letter in secretword:
        if letter == usertry:
            guessright = guessright + 1
            text.append(usertry)
        else:
            text.append('_')
    return guessright, ''.join(text)

reveal()
```

Here I return a `tuple` which is python's way of returning multiple values.  You can unpack the tuple in assignment if you wish:

```
guessright, text = reveal()
```

Answer (score 1):

> getting the function to return 2 outputs

```
def reveal():
    guessright = 0
    show = []
    for letter in secretword:
        if letter == usertry:
            guessright = guessright + 1
            show.append(usertry)
        else:
            show.append("_")
    return guessright, ''.join(show)

reveal()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reveal():
  guessright = 0
  result = ""
  for letter in secretword:
    if letter == usertry:
      guessright = guessright + 1
      result += usertry
    else:
      result += "_"
  return guessright,result

reveal()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can return two outputs by using a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

In your code, you could return in by doing something like:

```
def reveal():
    guessright = 0
    text = ''
    for letter in secretword:
        if letter == usertry:
            guessright = guessright + 1
            text += usertry,
        else:
            text += "_",
    print text
    return (guessright, text)

(guessright, text) = reveal()
```

Then you can access `guessright` and `text` outside of the scope of `reveal()'.

Comment: You're right, but I've always liked the way it looks.